# Simple regex pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to do this for some time now, but my Regex skills are pretty bad.
I have this text

```
<td class="red">
    One
</td>
<td>
    Two
</td>
```

And I want to get the value of "Two". I've tried multiple things like

```
<td>\n(.*)\n</td>
<td class=\"red\">\nOne\n</td>\n<td>\n(.*)\n</td>
```

And this is my C# source

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(src, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

I tried changing the `RegexOptions` with no luck. If anyone could help me it'd be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Use XElement class, it is much easier.

Comment: use `HTML agility pack` it would be much simpler rather then now

Comment: XElement.Parse("<Your xml fragment">).Elements("td").Last().Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `s` (*DotAll*) modifier forcing the dot `.` to match newline sequences as well.

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(src, @"(?s)<td>\s*(.*?)\s*</td>"))
         MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Note**: Follow `.*` with `?` for a *non-greedy* match here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply :

```
string expression = @"\<td\>[\s]*[A-Za-z]*[\s]*\</td\>";
```

And if you want to name your group

```
string expression = @"\<td\>[\s]*(?<groupName>([A-Za-z]*))[\s]*\</td\>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable dotall(`s`) modifier to make `.` to match a newline character.

```
(?<=<td>)\s*(\w*)\s*(?=<\/td>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sR6tF4)

And your code would be,

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?s)(?<=<td>)\s*(\w*)\s*(?=<\/td>)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```